# Azure Devops Search existing builds in Release Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

I have around 80 DLL's for which builds are created and pushed to Nuget using Azure Devops.
I am trying to create release pipeline by seggrigating different builds into different release pipelines.

But before creating I would like to identify if other release pipeline exist which using these builds as artifacts?
How could I identify if a release pipelines exits which already uses above builds.

Comment: As Matt said, you can use `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/ProjectSamples/WebAppDeploy/_apis/release/definitions?$expand=Artifacts&api-version=5.1` to list the details of all the release pipeline in one project. And the response will display which build is consumed by one release pipeline as artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the API for [Release Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and pass the artifacts expand option. I'll leave you to figure out the authentication piece (there are other answers that cover it).

Here's an example in PowerShell:

```
$uri = 'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.1&$expand=artifacts'

Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value | Select-Object id, artifacts
```